# chrome and IE not containing values after creating clone of file type

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am using the following code in order to create ajax upload script .my current task is to create a form on the fly using jquery so i do this by following code

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

<input id="files" name="file" type="file" value=""/>


<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#files').live('change', function () {
        var formId = 'jUploadForm';
        var form = $('<form action="" method="POST" name="' + formId + '" id="' + formId + '" enctype="multipart/form-data"></form>');
        var oldElement = $('#files');
        var newElement = $(oldElement).clone();


        $(oldElement).attr('id', 'files');
        $(oldElement).before(newElement);

        alert('fffffff');
        //alert(projectid);
        //return false;
        $(oldElement).appendTo(form);
    });
});
</script>
```

The error in aboce code is that after appending newElement using before the file value which i have select will be gonemeans whatever i select from browse button that will be present in the cloned file type but will be removed from the original file type i have.
above problem is only occuring in chrome and IE it is working fine in mozila
Please help

Comment: You're not setting the id of the new element, you're just resetting the ID of the original one.

Comment: how do you add the form element to the dom?

Comment: i will use appendTo function but that is not the problem if you run the code in mozilla and chroem then you will get the problem

Answer (score 1):

You can't put `oldElement` before `newElement` because you haven't added `newElement` to the DOM yet.

Similarly, you can't append `oldElement` to the `form` because `form` hasn't been added to the DOM, either.

Both `newElement` and `form` have to be added to the document after you create them before you can do any manipulation relative to them.

Finally, you're not doing anything when you run `$(oldElement).attr('id', 'files');` because the ID of `oldElement` already *is* `files`.

Comment: thank you for ansering but please run the code in both mozila and chorme then you will understand my problem in better way

Comment: I can see from examining your code that it won't do much of anything. The major problem I *can* see is that you're not adding your new elements to the DOM at any point. I'm sorry, but your English is too fragmented for me to understand exactly what you want to happen in your original question.

Comment: ok thank you for your comment.let me ask it in a different way just let me know when i am creating clone of file type ,will the clone be created with same value?means value of both the browse button will be same ?if yes then it is not happening in my case in chrome or IE